# Can't get .show to bring back content

Tags: jquery

So I am just trying to have when the arrow is clicked the picture hides, and that works. When I add the show it stops working and also says i have an error someone

here is the code

// JavaScript Document

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
   $(".arrow").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find(".content").hide(1000);
  });


$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".arrow_left").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().find(".content").show(1000);


    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="arrow">
    <img src="images/arrow.png" alt="arrow">
</div>
<div class="arrow_left">
    <img src="images/arrow2.png" alt "arrow">
</div>
<div id="main">
    <p></p>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <p></p>
</div>
<div class="content2">
    <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to show us your html, most probably, `$(".arrow_left").parent() cant find `.content`

Comment: Why 2 times `ready` event?

Comment: put your html as well. Aslo you can wrap both in one ready function

Comment: looks fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/e4dL34ku/1/ (except the syntax error)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
   $(".arrow").click(function() {
    $(".content").hide(1000);
  });


// $(document).ready(function(e) {  <<=== REMOVE THIS PART


    $(".arrow_left").click(function() {
        $(".content").show(1000);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first `$(document).ready` was not closed properly.

Do like

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  
   $(".arrow").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find(".content").hide(1000);
  });


   $(".arrow_left").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().find(".content").show(1000);


    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="arrow"> 
  Hide <img src="http://www.totaleyecareonline.com/images/icon-arrow_up_f1.gif" alt="arrow"> 
</div> 
<div class="arrow_left"> 
  Show <img src="http://i.technet.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC616682.gif" alt"arrow"> 
</div> 

<div id="main"> 
<p></p>
</div>

<div class="content"> 
  <p>Put something here</p> 
</div> 

<div class="content2"> <p></p> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h8fLyfs1/)

Many had mentioned, you don't need to declare 2 `.ready()` functions, 1 would do.